# SQL Data Base Sync

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server-2008

I want to Sync two different SQL Data base which is not in public IP, Is this possible with .Net Sync and WCF ?

Or I Need to add both DB in public IP ?

Comment: have you seen some of the redgate tools?

Comment: What exactly do you need to synchronize? Everything or just subset of information? Do you really mean replication?

Comment: some of the table .. actually i have two application one is online and one is offline both both have different/separate  db  but both db structure is same  .. and db is not in public id.. so when user enter some data then this data should be sync with  other ..

Comment: @Daniel A: no i have't see the redgate tools yet.. i thought this think work in .net sync ... 
redgate tool work with non public id DB ??

Comment: @PankajRana it will work if your computer has access to the databases

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like you are looking for a replication solution. Check out 
[Stairway to SQL Server Replication - SQLServerCentral.com](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/stairway/72401/) for an introduction to replication.